# AWS Athena unable to convert .csv integers to table values

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a simple csv file here

```
Joe, 30, Male, 3
Winston, 40, Male, 7
Emily, 18, Female, 5
Wendy, 32, Female, 4
```

Which I uploaded to an S3 bucket on AWS. Then, using Athena, I created a table with

- Correct S3 bucket path
- .csv as Data formt
- Columns as `name string, age int, gender string, consumed int`

The table is created successfully, but when I query it, only `name` and `gender` are there. The columns `age` and `consumed` are empty for all entries. Any ideas?

Comment: What does Describe Table display? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ddl/describe-table.html

Comment: `name                 string`
    `age                  int`                                      
    `gender               string`                                   
    `consumed             int`

Comment: Please post the actual output from DESCRIBE. Also post the query that you are running.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XSIUad0.png
Here's a screenshot of the result for DESCRIBE

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ggvqiFs.png Another screenshot for the result of DESCRIBE EXTENDED

Comment: Your table is defined correctly. There must be something wrong with your query.

Comment: Query string is "SELECT * FROM users". I suspect that it has something to do with Athena's table construction, because I get the same result if I try the same thing with an AWS Glue crawler. The crawler finds the .csv file, makes a table out of it, but leaves the age and consumed columns empty

Comment: I suspect that the spaces are causing problems with parsing your CSV. Spaces after commas are not part of the CSV standard.

Comment: As @JohnRotenstein mentioned, this issue is due to white space present after the commas. Just remove those white spaces, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces are the cause of not getting your desired values in defined data type. Just for the shake of testing, try making everything string and print them, you will see spaces in printed values also.

My first choice would be to remove spaces from the data itself. But if removal of spaces from data is not trivial, you can keep them as is and create table with those columns as string. Then you can internally convert them to int by first removing all the spaces and then casting to int. For example,

```
select cast(replace(age, '<whitespace>') as int) from <tablename>
```

Replace will remove all the whitespace from your string. And then cast will convert the string to integer. The same can be done for **consumed**.